# Why don't I receive my Django Channels Websocket message on the frontend?

Tags: django, rest, websocket, django-channels

It is connecting just fine but I don't receive the message I want to send.

```
class ArticleConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        print("WebSocket Connected")
        await self.accept()

    async def send(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        print("Hello")
        print("Sending WebSocket Text Data : ", text_data)
        print("Sending WebSocket Bytes Data : ", bytes_data)
        await send(text_data="Hi this is text")
        await send(bytes_data="Hi this is frame")

    async def disconnect(self):
        print("WebSocket Disconnected")
```

The terminal just shows this

```
WebSocket Connected
WebSocket CONNECT /api/ [127.0.0.1:52360]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /api/ [127.0.0.1:52362]
WebSocket Connected
WebSocket CONNECT /api/ [127.0.0.1:52362]
```

which means `async def send` isn't working. 
I also tried to change it to `async def receive`, still it doesn't work.

Here is the backend project repo :

https://www.github.com/prateekamana/tempstack

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't send screenshots of your IDE here but the code well formatted so people can copy it and use it to answer your question. Secondly, you're calling `self.send` inside `self.send` without any termination condition which will cause infinite recursion. You probably wanted to call `super().send` Finally, the `send` method isn't being called from anywhere so of course it won't run. I strongly advice you try to read the documentation and the tutorial again to learn more about the framework

Comment: But why do I have to call def send when I didn't have to call `def connect` or `def disconnect` ? Also I have posted the code properly formatted so can you please fix it ?

Comment: The send function sends an event to clients. But you have to call it for it to work - where to call it depends on your application logic. In the tutorial chat example, it is called from the receive function. So it receives a message from a client and sends it back. connect and disconnect are not called by you because those are events initiated by the connecting or disconnecting to the websocket. The sending of events however, has to be initiated by you or the client

Comment: Okay I just called `await super().send("Hello")` in `def connect` and it sent the message, now I need to send my DRF api ArticlesListView data into it, how can I pass that into send() ?

Comment: That's already a separate question. You can post another question for that with needed data and code. Also check StackOverflow for already existing questions

Answer (score 0):

you should send data to the frontend in JSON format.

await send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": "Hi this is text"}))